# How to consider a response_column int or Enum type using Flows

Tags: h2o

Most of the algorithms in h2o have a constraint in the `response_column`. For some of them, it must be an `Enum` type variable only and for other ones an  `int`. I have uploaded a data set where my `response_column` has the values: `0,1`, therefore it can be converted to `Enum` easily. Then due to this constraint for some algorithms, I can use my original type for the `response_column` but for testing other algorithms I need to convert it as `Enum`.

I was trying to create an additional column let's say `outputAsEnum`, but I didn't find a way how to create an additional column based on an existing one. I was trying to create a copy of my original data frame, but I didn't find the option for doing it.

Is there any simple way to have a Flow that allows considering several algorithms for the same output variable, but converting it properly before? (to `Enum` or to `int`)

*I have noticed too, that in order balance the classes for the `response_column`, the column type has to be an `Enum`. Is there any way to circumvent this?* Based on that, if I have imbalance data, I am forced to use only the algorithms that can work with `Enum` data type. This is just an example, there are other configuration parameters that would depend on the data type of the `response_column`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part would be easily doable using our Python/R APIs - Flow is more for trying out H2O, doing very basic operations - you'd have to prepare your dataset so it has the same column twice or upload the same dataset twice. This should only be a problem if you're running certain algorithms as regression problems and others as classification.

As for the second question - no, rebalancing is only supported for binomial/multinomial problems (we're achieving it via under/over sampling of certain classes).